# Efficient way to replace value in binary column with 1 in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a below data frame and I want to check binary columns and change non-empty value to 1.

```
a <- c("","a","a","","a")
b <- c("","b","b","b","b")
c <- c("c","","","","c")
d <- c("b","a","","c","d")

dt <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I am able to get the solution by looping and traversing through each column. But, I want some efficient solution because my data frame is really really large and the below solution is way much slower.

My Solution-

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(dt)))
{
  if(length(table(dt[,i]))==2){
  dt[which(dt[,i]!=""),i] <- 1
  }
}

Expected Output:

 a b c d
     1 b
 1 1   a
 1 1    
   1   c
 1 1 1 d
```

Is there a way to make it more efficient.

Comment: If you are looking at the "length" of individual cells, then you need `nchar` not `length`. Do you want to replace the empty values with `NA`, `0`, or something else? (It would really help if you provided your expected output.)

Comment: You're code looks mostly fine. I would just suggest that `length(unique(dt[, 1])) == 2)` will probably be faster than `table()`. If, as in your sample data, your columns are already factors you could do a little better reassigning the `levels`.

Comment: @d.b your code doesn't check for binary columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your concerns seems to be efficiency you may want to look at packages like `dplyr` or `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_all(dt, .funs = quo(if_else(n_distinct(.) <= 2L & . != "", "1", .)))

library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(uniqueN(x) <= 2L & x != "", 1, x))]
```

Comment: If using `data.table`, you can use the fast `uniqueN(x)` in place of `length(unique(x))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
inds = lengths(lapply(dt, unique)) == 2
dt[inds] = lapply(dt[inds], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x) != ""))
dt
#  a b c d
#1 0 0 1 b
#2 1 1 0 a
#3 1 1 0  
#4 0 1 0 c
#5 1 1 1 d
```

If you want `""` instead of `0`

```
dt[inds] = lapply(dt[inds], function(x) c("", 1)[(as.character(x) != "") + 1])
dt
#  a b c d
#1     1 b
#2 1 1   a
#3 1 1    
#4   1   c
#5 1 1 1 d
```

Comment: much better its just I will get 0's instead of empty char.

Comment: `nlevels` would be useful here

Comment: @Renu, `unique` would work even if the columns are not `factor`